# Tic Tac Toe game: when adding an O class to the Box class - then Box class takes on O's properties

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a Tic Tac Toe game and in JS I have a function that on click add either X or an O class to the Box class, so HTML ends up looking like this:

```
<div class="box O" id="two">
</div>
```

All boxes have the same class but different IDs.

My issue is: when I add O class then the respective Box becomes all messed up, .O position becomes crossed out in Styles (dev tools), and the height and wisth of the .box becomes the .O's h. and w.

The way I wrote my X CSS is by using ::before and ::after but if I do the same for O - then O turns into a mess between the two...

Please help me write a CSS for O so when i add it to a Box class - it doesnt turn into a mess.

My X css:

```
.X:before, .X:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: #FFC0CB;
    border-radius: 2px;
    top: 100px;
    left: 25px;
    animation-name: appear;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

.X:before{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.X:after{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Box CSS:

```
.box{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

separate boxes CSS based on ID:

```
#one{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

#two{
    border-right: 5px solid white;
    border-left: 5px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

O attempt #1 - affected Box CSS:

```
.O {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border: 8px solid #BCB88A;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

O attempt #2 - got mixed with X CSS:

```
.O::before,
    .O::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: #BCB88A;
    border-radius: 2px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.O::before {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.O::after {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

I need an O to be centered in the respective BOX when I add class to Box.
I'm using

```
one.classList.add("X");`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Create a functional snippet with the HTML, JavaScript and CSS in it perhaps rather than code fragments.